# Howto change the port in an URL using .htaccess

Tags: apache-http-server, port, url, htaccess

Using .htaccess, I need to change any URL of this kind
`https://example.com:80/webtrees/anything_else`
by exactly the same, but with 443 instead of 80

Note that I already have this in my .htaccess (it is there to change from http to https, it should stay there, and I do not understand this syntax):

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Thanks!

Comment: Port 443 is used by HTTPS connection

Comment: Just stop serving content on port 80. You can't rely on a redirect. Then they either get the redirected page or nothing.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered over at Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23027847/htaccess-specific-url-to-different-port

I'm going to modify the answer to fit your situation. It says "CONDITION: If not 443 then rewrite to https. This should strip out that port data. Your previous condition was protocol based and not port based.

```
    # redirect to 443 if current port is not 443 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**WARNING:**
I would not rely on these rules if you are trying to force https. I would turn off port 80 altogether. That way if they get around your rules they will see a 404 error.